# how to set date input data-options using jquery

Tags: jquery, calendar, jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using `JQuery-Mobile` `datebox` , and I want to set date input data-options using `JQuery`

edit:

*my question is : how to set date input data-options using jquery ?*

input code :

```
            <input 
                name="mydate" 
                id="mydate" 
                type="date"
                pickPageTheme="a"
                data-role="datebox"
                data-options='{"mode": "calbox" }' />
```

Comment: @Jasper the question is set in the title ! "how to set date input data-options using jquery?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datebox plugin internally relies on [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to parse the `data-options` attribute, so you can use its setter form instead of creating an explicit attribute:

```
$("#mydate").data("options", {
    mode: "calbox",
    highDates: ["2011-11-02", "2011-11-03"],
    highDatesAlt: ["2011-11-09", "2011-11-10"],
    pickPageOAHighButtonTheme: "b"
});
```

Do not forget to refresh the widget afterwards if it's already been created:

```
$("#mydate").datebox("refresh");
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, the code above won't work if the datebox widget was automatically created by the mobile framework on page load (since the `data-options` attribute is only parsed once). To work around that problem, you can use the `options` method:

```
$("#jqmdb").datebox("option", {
    mode: "calbox",
    highDatesAlt: ["2011-11-09", "2011-11-10"],
    highDates: ["2011-11-02", "2011-11-03"],
    pickPageOAHighButtonTheme: "b"
});
```

In that case, however, you have to specify `highDatesAlt` *before* `highDates`, or the former will be ignored.

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vXthd/9/).

Comment: thanks. does it the same for highDatesAlt in this code '      <input id="jqmdb" data-role="datebox" data-options='{ "mode":"calbox", "highDates": ["2011-11-02","2011-11-03"], "highDatesAlt": ["2011-11-09", "2011-11-10"], "pickPageOAHighButtonTheme": "b" }' name="jqmdb" />'  ??

Comment: Yes, it should, you only have to mentally "deserialize" the string into the Javascript object you pass to `data()`.

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer. You only have to write what you see in the string :) I removed the double quotes around the keys because I prefer that style, but it's perfectly valid to leave them.

Comment: Interesting, `refresh()` apparently does not update the state of an existing widget as expected. Destroying and recreating the widget somewhat works, but clones the UI elements, so `destroy()` also leaves something behind ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXthd/5/)). The best I could manage was to use the `option` method instead, but it seems to ignore `highDatesAlt` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXthd/6/)). I'll investigate further (it's getting late in my timezone) and keep you posted.

Comment: ok thank you very much. sorry to make you stay late, I will wait updates from,

Comment: give .datebox("hardreset") a shot instead - it's a bit more liberal than the refresh methood

Comment: @J.T.Sage I have used $("#mydate").datebox("hardreset"); rather than $("#mydate").datebox("refresh"); in http://jsfiddle.net/vXthd/  but nothing is changed

Comment: @Adham, finally got it to work, the `options` method requires `highDatesAlt` to be specified before `highDates` for some reason. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like:

```
<input name="myMEETINGdate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
      data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y","calUsePickers": true, "calNoHeader": true,"highDates": ["07-20-2012", "2011-12-25"] }'>
</input>
```

And Use:

```
$("#myminutesdate").datebox( "option",{highDates: ["2012-08-08", "2012-11-03"] });                       
$("#myminutesdate").datebox("refresh");
```

It would not work as in the first code snippet. Make sure you have the correct name and corresponding ID.

Correct Code:

```
<input name="myminutesdate" id="myminutesdate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
     data-options='{"mode": "calbox","dateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y","calUsePickers": true, "calNoHeader": true,"highDates": ["2012-12-07" , "2012-07-12"] }' >
</input>
```

It's silly but very important. Hope this helped.